# Пропал checkBox

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

У меня на странице есть 2 checkbox'а раньше они работали и их было видно, сейчас они выглядят как обычный input но при этом туда ничего нельзя писать, самих чекбоксов не видно, но при этом я заметил, что если нажимать туда где раньше был чекбокс, то он работает, но не отображается.

```
<div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <form method="post" asp-action="Create">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <h2 class="text-black-50 pl-3">Add Item</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td><label asp-for="Name"></label></td>
                                <td><label asp-for="Cost"></label></td>
                                <td><label asp-for="IsItThere"></label></td>
                                <td><label asp-for="IsItFood"></label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" /></td>
                                <td><input asp-for="Cost" class="form-control" /></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" asp-for="IsItThere" class="form-control" /></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" asp-for="IsItFood" class="form-control" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td><input type="submit" style="color: #2c3e50" class="btn btn-info w-75" value="create" /></td>
                                <td><a asp-action="List" asp-controller="Home" class="nav-link text-dark btn btn-danger w-75">GO BACK</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </form>

            @section Scripts{
                @{
                                    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" /> }
            }
        </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы задали чекбоксам класс [form-control](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/). Смотрите класс [form-check-input](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/)

Comment: нашел .form-check-input {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  margin-left: -1.25rem;
} Но что с ним не так, в других проектах он такой же вроде